# Java: How do you use key/value datastores like memcached with Java property file code?

Tags: java, properties, struts, memcached, wicket

We are trying to move away from property files as files on the file system and more want to use a server based key/value store.

Does anyone have any code to do this with Java.  Are there systems already built to connect to a server like memcached and build a property object with key values?

I want to do this in a struts web based project and a wicket web based project.

Comment: Do you want to keep configurations in the server (instead of .properties files inside the WAR), or want to store mutable data accessible by multiple servers? memcached is not really appropriate to hold configuration, and .properties files shouldn't be used to store mutable data...

Comment: ... or do you want to store mutable configuration accessible by multiple servers?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) which offers tons (well almost) ways to load and save config data.

Answer (score 0):

The memcached wiki [lists a handful of Java clients](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients#Java).